# Making text more readable Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have this image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojhYe.jpg

That when looking at it, a human can see that it says PINE (N) on the top line and PI on the second line. The problem I have is that when using tesseract-ocr to read what the text says it has pretty bad outputs. I have a lot of images like this and need to automate this process, so doing it manually is not idea. I have used imagemagick to get it in the current state, but would like to know if there is any way to make this image more readable by possibly connecting the close areas of black. I know almost nothing about image manipulation so I don't know where to begin searching. If anyone knows a method for making this more readable I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty tricky problem, and the solution that works best will depend sensitively on characteristics of the image - what scale is the type?  how degraded is the image?  The boundary between details that you want to keep and degradation that you want to fix is something that only the human operator can decide, so there is no automated one-size-fits-all solution for this problem, and you should expect to do some experimentation.

The basic technique is that you want to adjust the value of each pixel in the image to be similar to the pixels that surround it.  Put in those terms, you might realise that this is just a blur operation.  After you blur the image though, you are left with letters with fuzzy edges, so to get crisp letters again, that's a threshold operation - you set a threshold level of gray, and everything lighter than that shade of gray becomes white and everything darker than the threshold becomes black.  The blur plus threshold combination gives you a wide range of effects that you can use to make text more (or less) legible.  For the example image given, I had pretty good results with a blur radius of 5 and a threshold level of 70%.

```
convert QFSimZX.jpg -blur 5 -threshold 70% output.png
```

[image: blur and threshold]

You can get more sophisticated than this if needed, by implementing a custom blur function with the `-fx` operator.  Fx is powerful but somewhat complex, and you can read about it here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php .  I tried a quick fx expression that filled in a pixel based first on its above and below neighbors, then on its left and right neighbors.  This technique really allows you to fine tune which pixels are considered in computing the blur:

```
convert QFSimZX.jpg -monochrome \
    -fx 'p[0,-1]+p[0,1] >= 2 ? 1 : 0' \
    -fx 'p[-1,0]+p[1,0] >= 2 ? 1 : 0' \
    output.png
```

[image: fx method]

Comment: This answer is out of date as Imagemagick now has a better tool for this called morphology.